# PHP: Instantiating class by object property value

Tags: php

Is there no way to instantiate a new class instance using the value of an object property?

```php
$arg = 'hello';
$class = $foo->bar;
$instance = new $class($arg);
```

This works fine, but I'd like to skip the 2nd line and just do something like:

```php
$instance = new {$foo->bar}($arg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.0.4+ this works fine:

```
$instance = new $foo->bar($arg);
```

Full example:

```
<?php
$foo = new foo();
$arg = 'hello';
$class = $foo->bar;
$instance = new $class($arg);
$instance = new $foo->bar($arg); // your requested shorthand

class foo {
    public $bar = 'bar';
}

class bar {
    public function __construct($arg) {
        echo $arg;
    }
}
```

see this [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f36086f9d5b7b62dec0bb488b4ea6e4219fc67f).

Comment: Thanks, maybe I was thrown off by the syntax highlighting, it looks like the `$foo->bar()` is being called.